# Google sheets checkmark conditional Formating

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, checkbox, sum, google-sheets-formula

I need help with Google spreadsheet checkmark conditional formatting. ***Please see the image for a better understanding***. When I click on the `C2` cells checkmark then automatically `A2` cells *$10* will be selected and added to the `E5` cells. When I click on the `B6` checkmark then automatically `A6` cells *$40* will be selected and added to the `E5` cells. Summary of the concept: When I checkmark any cells (from `B2` to `B9` & `C2` to `C9`) the same row (From A column) number will be added automatically to the specific cells(to `E5` cells). How do I do it?

Sheet Link (I have given edit permission, you can edit it) - [Go to sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HBiQDzI7tiHRMQhE7coOIDM2ww_KmDIFy_mUclqgOtQ/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Your explanation and image explanation do not match. When both cells of same row is checked, do you want to add only one value from those same row?

Comment: I am really sorry about this. Yes, I want to add only one value from the same row.

Comment: Check my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF(B2:C9=TRUE, A2:A9, 0)))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF((B2:B9=TRUE)+(C2:C9=TRUE), A2:A9, 0)))
```

[image]

or try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B9=TRUE)*(C2:C9=TRUE)*A2:A9)
```

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B9=TRUE)+(C2:C9=TRUE))*A2:A9)
```

Comment: Awesome. I try too many times to do it. But I can't able to do it. Your formula awesome it's works

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=QUERY(A2:C9,"select sum(A) where B=True or C=True label sum(A) ''")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u so much for giving your best afford. It works but the total amount needs to calculate by both people(John & Markon) from the same row. Again want to say thank u so much for giving me your valuable time and afford. A person did it.